# Create new vector with all elements between elements of two equal length vectors

Tags: r

I am cleaning out interjections and heckles from the minutes of parliamentary sessions. I have transformed the PDF into a vector where each element contains one line of the minutes.

Using regular expressions, I have identified the indices of the lines where an interjection starts (it begins with "(") and where it ends (it ends with ")"), resulting in two equal length vectors.

To figure out now which lines to drop, I need to create a new vector that contains both the starting points and the end points, as well as all the lines in between.

As an example:

```r
start <- c(1, 6, 9, 24)
end <- c(3, 7, 12, 27)
```

The resulting vector in this case should be equivalent to:

```r
interjections <- c(1,2,3,6,7,9,10,11,12,24,25,26,27)
```

or alternatively:

```r
interjection <- c(1:3, 6:7, 9:12, 24:27)
```

I am sure there is a simple way to do this, but I just cannot get it to work properly. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map` or `mapply` should work for equal length vectors. If they are not equal length it will start to recycle the shorter one.

```
start <- c(1, 6, 9, 24)
end <- c(3, 7, 12, 27)

interjection <- Map(`:`, start, end)
interjection
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 7

[[3]]
[1]  9 10 11 12

[[4]]
[1] 24 25 26 27

interjections <- unlist(interjection)
interjections
[1]  1  2  3  6  7  9 10 11 12 24 25 26 27
```

Comment: @DominicGohla, glad it helped!! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when it solves your issue :)